# { discord.js v12 } Per-Server Settings/Config

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm currently working on a public discord bot, and I wanted to make the server decide their settings, how am I able to make per server settings, I understand I need a database like sqlite3 or MySQL, but what would the code be?

Comment: What have you already tried? Is there a specific database you want to use?

Comment: No, I don't have a specific, I tried mongoose and enmap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd highly doubt that you'd want to use config files for each discord server, mostly because they take up so much space and they have a chance to be corrupted over frequent changes to the .json, so what you want to do is use enmaps.
https://gist.github.com/eslachance/5c539ccebde9fa76340fb5d54889aa22

If you're wanting to ask further questions about this here's the enmap Discord:
https://discord.gg/bRFyWp3

Comment: Thanks, I got enmap up and running!

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have the prefix of your bot set up like this on `index.js` and that your bot's name is `@Ma Boop Boi#1234`:

```
let prefix = "!";
```

but a bot's user already calls another bot called `@Butler#6789` on their server **(Server B)** by also using `"!"`. `@Ma Boop Boi` needs to fetch the `let prefix` variable from a `JSON` file that would be thrown by some database so you can have different prefix values. On the `discord.js` library, servers are known as `guild`.

object-file-1.json

```
{
  "guild-id": "123456789012345678",
  "prefix": "!"
}
```

object-file-2.json

```
{
  "guild-id": "987654321098765432",
  "prefix": "-"
}
```

Comment: So would I have to put a file for each guild individually, cause my bots in 32 servers

Comment: Maybe not one file per guild, but one json object for each server.

Comment: So there should be just one file called settings.json in which all the objects are inside? but then how could one obtain for example the prefix of a particular guildid? which query to use?

Comment: Not a file, but a database. I used JSON files as examples, so you would consider using `MongoDB`